# Extracting user input from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on a simple app in which a bar tender can do the beer pay off automatically. The articles (beer, wine, whisky etc) are listed in a database and I use a SimpleCursorAdapter to map all the articles from the database to a ListView. Works perfectly.

So now it displays a list of articles, prices and a textfield where the bartender can input the quantity of the order (ex 10 beer). 
Problem: I don't know how I can get those quantities back from the ListView. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the OnItemClickListener of your ListView, you can use the View view Parameter to access Sub-Items of the List View Item. You could replace the TextView in the following example with your EditText. Replace android.R.id.text1 with your R.id.x.

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                TextView testAccess = (TextView)(view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), testAccess.getText()
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do something
              }
            });
```

Comment: I am not particularly interested in listening to the edittexts. I just want to "read" whats in it when the bar tender pushes some other button outside of the listview. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to do it is to set a button click listener inside of your Adapter getView() method, upon click that button can pull the value out of the EditText. Since you are inside the getView() method you should still have a reference to the EditText that you need.

Comment: This means that I need to make my own adapter extension, right? So far I managed to do without. But I guess if there is no other option then I better go find out how that works. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make your own custom adapter that extends the normal CursorAdapter